# Samsung M2020 on Ubuntu

Tags: samsung

I'm new to linux and I know nothing about coding and using the terminal. I searched google for a way to connect Samsung M2020 printer to my computer running ubuntu but i didn't find. What should I do now?

Comment: here you can read everything you will need, it's well written even for beginners: http://www.bchemnet.com/suldr/index.html

Comment: Above links don't seem to work, found it here: http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_LEVANT&CttFileID=6285092&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=SL-M2020&VPath=DR/201510/20151028115008613/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Open gnome-terminal via Ubuntu dash or via shortcut ctrl+alt+t and paste following commands:

1. Download driver from Samsung site (link is dead, download the linux version from http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/SL-M2020/SAU)

   ```
   wget 'http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_LEVANT&CttFileID=5999976&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=SL-M2020&VPath=DR/201503/20150311160833703/ULD_v1.00.35.tar.gz'
   ```
2. Unpack it

   ```
   tar zxvf ULD_v1.00.35.tar.gz
   ```
3. Install driver, with sudo command you need to enter your root password.

   ```
   sudo ./uld/install.sh
   ```
4. Now, you should be able to to add your printer via Printers program. Add it as network printer or simply plug it in via USB and it should work.

Comment: Thank you very much it worked as said, but I can't print on both sides of the paper! the option is disabled how could i enable it?

Comment: I don't have any printer installed for now, so i can't check it. Try to find some option in Printer preferences.  You can also try execute  `lpoptions -l | grep -i duplex`. It should print state of duplex mode in your system.

[link](https://askubuntu.com/a/4965/316028) check this answer for mode details

Comment: `wget http://org.downloadcenter.samsung.com/downloadfile/ContentsFile.aspx?CDSite=UNI_LEVANT&CttFileID=6285092&CDCttType=DR&ModelType=N&ModelName=SL-M2020&VPath=DR/201510/20151028115008613/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz`

or you can find it here
http://www.samsung.com/levant/support/model/SL-M2020/SAU

Comment: "Terminated by user problem" described at https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2289357 and solved as per comment #4 therein.

Comment: New link for download after HP acquisition of Samsung Printers: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/selfservice/samsung-xpress-sl-m2010-laser-printer-series/16462586

Comment: I'm grateful that the driver works, but I'd like to know what it has installed and where without having to inspect the installation scripts.

Comment: This helped!
One additional issue was - I added printer to Ubuntu before installing the driver.

Then after driver installation I had to first remove the printer from Ubuntu and re-add it for it to work

Comment: This answer is still working in 2022.  And thanks to @NefedovEfim for the tip!

Comment: If anyone is building inside Docker or such, you can set `SKIP_EULA_PAGER` to skip the pager, along with appropriate input piped in for the prompts

Answer (score 8):

Download Linux driver: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201510/20151028115008613/uld_v1.00.36_00.91.tar.gz

Go to http://localhost:631/admin to add the printer using cups web-based manager. Administration > add printer. Follow the steps until ending up with the question where to find the correct ppd file.

Now, extract the file downloaded in the first step and navigate using the cups admin panel's ppd browse button for the following file:
~/Downloads/samsungm2020_driver/noarch/share/ppd/Samsung_M2020_Series.ppd

Done.

Good Luck!

Comment: I'd like to add that the latest Samsung drivers (uld_V1.00.39_01.17) from the HP website did not work for me. So make sure you download the driver as mentioned in this answer (uld_v1.00.36_00.91). That one made it work instantly, even configured over a network. No need to enter the CUPS interface, just run `sudo ./install.sh`.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a model which is slightly different from the M2020 (mine was M2026), the samsung printers support is now being done by hp.com: 
http://www8.hp.com/us/en/printers/samsung.html

for checking your model direct: https://support.hp.com/us-en/drivers/printers

Comment: I really appreciate this information. I also have the M2026 printer and this driver works the best.