# change M2020 printer WiFi configuration using USB

Tags: networking, wireless, usb, printing, samsung

I have an M2020 printer, I already installed in one Ubuntu machine (using uld drivers more like [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/645681/samsung-m2020-on-ubuntu) post),but when I tried to connect through an USB and try to install it on a laptop it doesn't recognize the printer so I can't add it in an easy way. I already configured the wifi long ago but it failed here at the University so I can't access the printer via hitting WPS button or something like that. Now I have another network available so I could try to change the network, password, and other details so I can connect to it via wifi. I can't use the Windows or Mac tools provided by Samsung.

How can I configure the network again if I only can connect it via USB? I have printed the 2 pages after hitting WPS for 10 seconds.
Using Ubuntu Gnome 16.04

Comment: A standalone networked printer configuration is independent from the OSes where it will used.  It's really not clear what you're asking nor what you want to do.

Comment: I need to put another network so I can connect to it again.  I edited the question. I can't use the Window tools to connect to it.

Comment: First of all you cannot add network devices to a corporate or institutional network without proper authorization of the system and network admins. Regarding configuration I doubt that any manufacturer makes a WiFi enabled printer that must be configured using a Windows software. Please read: http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/UM/201601/20160105120755203/EN/English/English/manual/BABBHHBB.htm?isTocLink=fixed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible to reset the Wi-Fi settings of your M2020 printer using Samsung's PSU ("Printer Settings Utility").

Highly inspired from [this post](https://ro-che.info/articles/2014-04-21-wireless-samsung-printer-linux), I've ended up moving the required files in the same folder and adding my user to the `lp` group.

### Download utilities

Fetch the utilities directly from [here](https://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201110/20111019151150392/PSU_1.01.tar.gz) and extract the archive somewhere.

```sh
wget http://downloadcenter.samsung.com/content/DR/201110/20111019151150392/PSU_1.01.tar.gz
tar xzf PSU_1.01.tar.gz
```

### Preparing `wirelesssetup`

The following shared libraries are needed for the tool to work. Copy or extract the files into the same folder where `wirelesssetup` is placed.

I'm running an x64 machine but a similar procedure can be followed for older machines.

- `libnetsnmp.so.10` copy from `PSU_1.01/cdroot/Linux/psu/share/lib64/libnetsnmp.so.10.0.2`
- `libqt-mt.so.3` copy from `PSU_1.01/cdroot/Linux/psu/share/lib64/libqt-mt.so.3.0.5`
- `libstdc++.so.5` extract from `PSU_1.01/cdroot/Linux/psu/share/libstdc++-5-x86_64.tar.gz` | `/usr/lib64/libstdc++.so.5.0.7`

Eventually, you should end up with this folder structure:

```sh
PSU_1.01/cdroot/Linux/wirelesssetup/bin64
├── libnetsnmp.so.10
├── libqt-mt.so.3
├── libstdc++.so.5
└── wirelesssetup
```

### Add user to `lp` group

In order for the tool to communicate with the printer, your user must be part of the `lp` group. Check if your user is in the group with:

```sh
id -Gn
> lp adm tty dialout cdrom sudo ...
```

To add your user to the `lp` group, use the following commands:

```sh
sudo usermod -a -G lp username
newgrp lp
```

### Run `wirelesssetup`

Make sure that your printer is connected to a USB port. Then list the available devices with:

```sh
ls /dev/usb/lp*
```

To start the GUI tool, run the following command:

```sh
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=./:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH ./wirelesssetup /dev/usb/lp0
```

If everything went right the tool should start printing several lines in the console and a GUI should pop up.

```
IOClientUsbEp0::init()
IODeviceLocker::IODeviceLocker(0x7ffcf08e6620,43)
    m_isValid=1
    devID[120]: <MFG:Samsung;CMD:SPL,URF,FWV,PIC,EXT,DCU;MDL:M2020 Series;CLS:PRINTER;CID:SA_SPLV3_BW;MODE:SPL3,R000105,SCP;STATUS:BUSY;>
IOClientUsbEp0::findUsbDevice(0x7ffcf08e6620)
IOClientUsbEp0::get_usb_bus_address: m_usblp: name=</dev/usb/lp0>
IODeviceLocker::IODeviceLocker(0x7ffcf08e6620,43)
    m_isValid=1
INFO: usb_control_msg(,0xc1,0xe0,0x0100,0x0000,0x1428f80,255,5000)
I/O: ep0: HOST>FW: c1 e0 0100 0000 00ff [0 bytes of data]
I/O: ep0: HOST<FW: 404D00000000000C000C402C0000502C...[255 bytes of data]
    extDevID[255]: <CMD:PV3,ALL,WSP,CMP,IDS,EPMWSP,WPS,WFD,WWS,NFC1,GCP,AMPV,RDS,APO,WIN8,OTG,SBYOFF,CI_19,URL;>
...
```

[image: wirelesssetup GUI]