# Install Samsung M2070 printer on Ubuntu

Tags: drivers, printing, samsung

I want to connect my Samsung M2070 printer to my computer running Ubuntu but I didn't find any up-to-date solutions. I followed [these instructions on the forum about another printer](https://askubuntu.com/a/980437/1057583), the printer appears in the printers list, I linked it to the ppd file, but nothing happens when I try to print a page. 
What can I do now?
(I'm new to Linux)
Thank you.

Comment: What does the `lpstat -t` command show? Point a web browser to http://localhost:631/admin and add your printer there.

Comment: Hi! I added the printer as you said and I tried again to print a file (the printer showed up in the printers list). But it says "Printing was stopped" (in French l'impression a été arrêtée").

Comment: lpstat -t gives :

Comment: scheduler is running
no system default destination
matériel pour M2070-Series : usb://Samsung/M2070%20Series?serial=ZF5RB8KDCA00CWN&interface=1
matériel pour Samsung_M2070_Series : usb://Samsung/M2070%20Series?serial=ZF5RB8KDCA00CWN&interface=1
M2070-Series accepte des requêtes depuis sam. 18 avril 2020 11:52:03 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series accepte des requêtes depuis sam. 18 avril 2020 11:54:57 CEST
printer M2070-Series is idle.  enabled since sam. 18 avril 2020 11:52:03 CEST
 File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl" not available: No such file or directory

Comment: printer Samsung_M2070_Series is idle.  enabled since sam. 18 avril 2020 11:54:57 CEST
 File "/usr/lib/cups/filter/rastertospl" not available: No such file or directory
M2070-Series-5          ariane           56320   sam. 18 avril 2020 11:50:42 CEST
M2070-Series-6          ariane           56320   sam. 18 avril 2020 11:52:03 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series-7  ariane           56320   sam. 18 avril 2020 11:52:22 CEST
Samsung_M2070_Series-8  ariane           56320   sam. 18 avril 2020 11:54:57 CEST

Answer (score 1):

There's a good step-by-step description of what to do on the German ubuntuusers forum:

https://forum.ubuntuusers.de/topic/installation-von-samsung-m2070fw-anschluss-via/

Go to the last post of this thread (from "24. August 2019 21:47") and follow the steps described in that post carefully. You might not be able to understand the German, but you will be able to fix your problem.

Comment: While it is good to add information via links, it is even better to include the info from the link into your answer, because links can disappeaer.